# AWS Network Policy for EMR Web UIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-security-group

I have Airflow running in an EC2 instance and I want it to be able to hit all the endpoints running in EMR.

I tried updating the security group on the EMR master node to allow all connections from the public IP of the Ec2 instance. (All ports), but still can't hit anything.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to troubleshoot network-related issues (which this one is) without much information about what types of jobs are being run and your physical environment. That having been said, I'd suggest a couple things:

1. Change your security group inbound rules to be based on the security group that your EC2 is in, instead of using the public IP of the ec2 instance. This is better for both security reasons (you're not guaranteed to always own that public IP) and for flexibility (if you have to destroy and rebuild your ec2 instance, you don't need to change it). This may be enough to solve the issue by itself, but if it's not:
2. Update the security group for both the main node AND the worker nodes of EMR. Depending on what type of job you're submitting and how you're submitting it, some jobs only require communication with the main node and others will require connection to other core nodes.